# Inversion usage in "Despite being cheap and efficient, hardly does crayon capture the artists’ true intention."

Tags: inversion

Is it correct to use inversion in the second part of the following sentence?

> Despite being cheap and efficient, hardly does crayon capture the artists’ true intention.

Is it better to revise the sentence as follows?

> Hardly does crayon capture the artists’ true intention in spite of
> being cheap and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inversion "hardly does crayon" doesn't fit in either sentence. It should be replaced by "crayon hardly...".

With that fix, either of these sentences works:

> Despite being cheap and efficient, crayon hardly captures the artist's true intention.

> Crayon hardly captures the artist's true intention, in spite of being cheap and efficient.

I changed **artists'** to singular **artist's**, because several artists will probably have different intentions. You could also say **artists' true intentions**.

Comment: Why it doesn't fit? Please tell me the reason. Thanks

Comment: See James K's answer. You could use that expression in a dramatic sentence: "Hardly had the sun set before the prowling predators circled in." Your sentence doesn't seem at all dramatic, just technical.

Answer (score 2):

[Inversion with a negative adverb](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/towards-advanced/unit-25/session-1) is possible, but a very "marked" expression. It makes a surprisingly dramatic sentence.  It would be correct and unremarkable to use the uninverted form.

This is linguist equivalent of grabbing someone and shaking them as you tell me that the crayon was no good. Sometimes that is a good idea, but if you do it too often, or for things that are not really important, it weakens the effect.